# How to find out storage used by stages to clean out

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

UI shows higher than normal usage for Stage, how to identify which internal/user/table stages have files need to be purged?

`STORAGE_USAGE` or `STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY` views in `ACCOUNT_HISTORY` are  not helpful, since they only provide daily averages for total used space.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all stages for current user using

```
ls @~;
```

This will return

- Stage Name
- Size
- MD5 Value
- Last modified date

Comment: User stages are only one of the stages in Snowflake, also only users can run the above command to see what's in their user stage. Your answer has nothing to do with my question.